# vb 2010 mysql insert record operation inserts a blank record but no data is inserted

Tags: mysql, vb.net, insert

I am trying to develop a utility in vb 2010, which will store values from Datagridview control to a mysql table

Steps 
1) Datagrid cell values are stored in an array
2) Array values are used .AddWithValue() function

Present status: Only a blank record is inserted. Data is missing.

Please refer to following code.

```
         Function insertRec()
         'dgExistingProject is datagridview control embedded on the form
         Dim ServerString As String = "Server=pnserver;User ID=root;
         Password=; Database=prayer_net"
         Dim Arr(RCount) As String
         Dim SQLConn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
         SQLConn.ConnectionString = ServerString
         dim I as Integer
         For I = 0 To RCount
                Arr(I) = dgExistingProject.Rows(I).Cells(1).Value
         Next
            Try
                Dim dt As Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd 
                      HH:mm:ss")
                Dim projName as Integer=Arr(4)
                Using sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
                    With sqlCommand
                        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO dyn_dwg_register 
                     (file_name,file_location,dwg_description,  
                     project_id,created_by, created_on)" & _
                                      " values (@file_name, @file_location, @dwg_description, @project_id, @created_by, @created_on)"
                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        .Connection = SQLConn
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_name", Arr(0))
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_location", Arr(1))
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwg_description", Arr(2))
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_id", ProjName)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@created_by", Arr(4))
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@created_on", dt)
                    End With
                    Try
                        SQLConn.Open()
                        If SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                            Dim ID As Integer = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End If
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
                    Finally
                        SQLConn.Close()
                    End Try
                End Using
            Catch e As Exception
                  MsgBox (e.Message.ToString)
            End Try
End Function
```

Rajendra Nadkar

Comment: Obviously I have committed some mistake, but have become just blank. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i had written a code in C# where i had to store data from a datagrid to SQL database. I used the following code. I think it will help you.

```
string sqlquery = "UPDATE TableName set ColumnName1=@param1 where ColumnName2=@param2";
using (OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, dbCon))
{
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[1, index].Value));
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@param2", OleDbType.VarWChar)).Value = "somevalue";
            updateDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            updateDbCmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try that syntax [Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1[1, index].Value));] out.

Comment: Also check if your array has the values. Possibly the array is blank.

Comment: Basically I can update the record, problem occurs when we are inserting a new record.

Comment: Array is not blank. It was verified by adding a msgbox in With sqlCommand... End With block

Comment: .Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Arr(0)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_location", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Arr(1)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwg_description", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Arr(2)
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = ProjName
                        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@created_by", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Arr(4)

Comment: .Parameters.Add("@file_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Arr(0)

Comment: Monica, thanks, will try it out right out and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I changed the field name prefix @ to ? and things became smooth. In an earlier question in Feb 11, Stelian Matei suggested this edit, though later on Giezel Esteves reversed it. (Original question asked by user1176607 in Feb '10)

I guess I need to refer to documentation more thoroughly. Anyways I am giving the working code here if you or anybody interested in it.

```
        Dim qry As String = "INSERT INTO dyn_dwg_register (`file_name` , `file_location`, `dwg_description`, `project_id`, `created_by`)" & _
                                  " values (?file_name, ?file_location, ?dwg_description, ?project_id, ?created_by)"
        Dim sqlCommand As MySqlCommand
        sqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(qry, SQLConn)
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        With sqlCommand
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("?file_name", Arr(0))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("?file_location", Arr(1))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("?dwg_description", Arr(2))
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("?project_id", ProjName)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("?created_by", Arr(2))
        End With
```